# Simple form for remote true responding with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a remote true. When i hit submit, i am only responding with js. The problem is that the server is not responding with javasctipt, but rather with html.

My form.

```
= simple_form_for @company, :remote => true,  :url => {:controller => 'companies', :action => 'update_company'}, :html => { :multipart => true, :class => 'company_name' }  do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :submit
```

In my controller

```
def update_company
  if @company.update(company_attributes)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I am requiring all jquery files.
This is working everywhere but in this action.

My response header from server:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 24 Sep 2015 22:02:17 GMT
Server:nginx/1.8.0 + Phusion Passenger 5.0.13
Status:406 Not Acceptable
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000
X-Powered-By:Phusion Passenger 5.0.13
```

My request header:

```
Accept:text/javascript
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1048
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: _LongFreakingHash
```

Let me know if you need more information. I am at a loss here.
If you have come across this before, your input would help me tons.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this

```
= simple_form_for @company, :remote => true,  :url => {:controller => 'companies', :action => 'update_company'}, :html => { :multipart => true, :class => 'company_name' }  do |f|
```

to

```
= simple_form_for @company, :url => {:controller => 'companies', :action => 'update_company', :remote => true }, :html => { :multipart => true, :class => 'company_name' }  do |f|
```